# empty or # link for my account

Tags: magento2, theme, plugin, link

I need to set **`My account`** link to be `#` . It shouldn't redirect anywhere.

There's a possible way to set it as # using **plugin** in module.

But I want to do it in theme. Is there's a way to **achieve** in **theme**?

Comment: Do you need to add "#" for header My accocunt link?

Comment: Yes you are right @aravind

Answer (score 1):

It's usually bad practice to use '#' or 'javascript:void()' in href tag. I would not recommend this, instead you can prevent the link from firing with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-account-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Instead of using jQuery, I recommend to just change the block with custom template.

If you look into `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`
you can see how Magento creates the link.

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

As there is no template directly related to Customer Account link, I would suggest that you remove the default Magento block that handles My Account link.

1) Create the file `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your-theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

2) Add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my-custom-account-link" template="my-account.phtml" before="register-link"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- remove My Account Link -->
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

3) Create your custom template in `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your-theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/my-account.phtml` and add your content.